# use with class file into wp_ajax hook

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to use a class from another file within a wp_ajax hook
And the call returns a 500 status code

I added the class with incloud (),

I tried to put the whole class inside the function and it worked fine.

Is there a way to use a class file within the wp_ajax function?

This is the code in the function.php file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'ajax_import_rows_init' );
function ajax_import_rows_init() {

    wp_register_script( 'ajax_import_rows', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/ajax_import_rows.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_import_rows' );

    $rows_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'ajax_rows_nonce' );

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_import_rows', 'ajax_import_opject', array(
        'ajaxurl'   =>  admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'nonce'     =>  $rows_nonce
    ));

   add_action('wp_ajax_import_list_rows', 'response_list_rows');
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_import_list_rows', 'response_list_rows');
}

function response_list_rows(){

    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_rows_nonce', 'nonce' );

    include_once(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fileds.php');   

    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

    $list_rows = new fields_ACF($post_id);
    $list_rows_json = json_encode( $list_rows -> fileds);
    echo( $list_rows_json);

    die();
}
```

This is the class in the fields.php file:

```
class fields_ACF{

public $fileds =array();

public function fields_ACF($post_id){

    $income     =     $this ->  income($post_id);
    $expenses   =     $this ->  expenses($post_id);
    $debts      =     $this ->  debts($post_id);

    return(
        $this -> fileds["income"]   =   $income and 
        $this -> fileds["expenses"] =   $expenses and 
        $this -> fileds["debts"]    =   $debts
    );
    //$this -> fileds = array();

}

//פונקציה להכנסות
private function income($post_id){

    $a =array();
    $fileds = array();

    if( have_rows('revenue', $post_id) ):
        while(have_rows('revenue', $post_id) ): the_row();

            /*****הוצאת כמות שיש מכל קטגוריה***********/
            array_push($a, get_sub_field('id_cat', $post_id));
            $count_rows_registered = array_count_values($a);

    endwhile;
    endif;

    if( have_rows('types_income', 'option') ):
        while(have_rows('types_income', 'option') ): the_row();
            $type_no = get_sub_field('type_income_no');
            $title = get_sub_field('type_income_name');
            if( have_rows('cat_income', 'option') ):
                while( have_rows('cat_income', 'option') ): the_row();
                    $cat_income_no = get_sub_field('cat_income_no');
                    $cat_income_name = get_sub_field('cat_income_name');
                    if( have_rows('settings_cat') ):
                    while( have_rows('settings_cat') ): the_row();
                    $day_field  = get_sub_field('day_in_months');
                    $month_field = get_sub_field('months');
                    endwhile;
                    endif;                   
                    $fileds[$type_no]['name']=$title;
                    $fileds[$type_no]['content'][$cat_income_no]['name']= $cat_income_name;
                    $fileds[$type_no]['content'][$cat_income_no]['settings']=[
                        'day_field' => $day_field,
                        'month_field' => $month_field
                        ];
                    $fileds[$type_no]['content'][$cat_income_no]['count_rows_registered']=$count_rows_registered[$cat_income_no];
                    $fileds[$type_no]['content'][$cat_income_no]['rows_registered']=[];
                endwhile;
            endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;


    if( have_rows('revenue', $post_id) ):
        while(have_rows('revenue', $post_id) ): the_row();
            /********הכנסת תוכן השורות במערך הכללי********/
            $row =array(
                'index_row'         =>  get_row_index(),
                'date_registered'   =>  get_sub_field('Date_typed'),
                'type'              =>  get_sub_field('type'),
                'ID_type'           =>  get_sub_field('id_type'),
                'category_name'     =>  get_sub_field('category_Revenue'),
                'ID_category'       =>  get_sub_field('id_cat'),
                'dete_in_payment'   =>  get_sub_field('Date_payment'),
                'Amount'            =>  get_sub_field('total'),
                'method_payment'    =>  get_sub_field('method')
            );

            $fileds[$row['ID_type']]['content'][$row['ID_category']]['rows_registered'][]=$row;
        endwhile;
    endif;

    return($fileds);

}

//פונקציה להוצאות    
private function expenses($post_id){

    $a =array();
    $fileds = array();

    if( have_rows('expenses', $post_id) ):
        while(have_rows('expenses', $post_id) ): the_row();

            /*****הוצאת כמות שיש מכל קטגוריה***********/
            array_push($a, get_sub_field('id_cat', $post_id));
            $count_rows_registered = array_count_values($a);

    endwhile;
    endif;

    if( have_rows('types_expenses', 'option') ):
        while(have_rows('types_expenses', 'option') ): the_row();
            $type_no = get_sub_field('type_expenses_no');
            $title = get_sub_field('type_expenses_name');
            if( have_rows('cat_expenses', 'option') ):
                while( have_rows('cat_expenses', 'option') ): the_row();
                    $cat_income_no = get_sub_field('cat_expenses_no');
                    $cat_income_name = get_sub_field('cat_expenses_name');
                    if( have_rows('settings_cat') ):
                    while( have_rows('settings_cat') ): the_row();
                    $day_field  = get_sub_field('day_in_months');
                    $month_field = get_sub_field('months');
                    endwhile;
                    endif;                   
                    $fileds[$type_no]['name']=$title;
                    $fileds[$type_no]['content'][$cat_income_no]['name']= $cat_income_name;
                    $fileds[$type_no]['content'][$cat_income_no]['settings']=[
                        'day_field' => $day_field,
                        'month_field' => $month_field
                        ];
                    $fileds[$type_no]['content'][$cat_income_no]['count_rows_registered']=$count_rows_registered[$cat_income_no];
                    $fileds[$type_no]['content'][$cat_income_no]['rows_registered']=[];

                endwhile;
            endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;


    if( have_rows('expenses', $post_id) ):
        while(have_rows('expenses', $post_id) ): the_row();
            /********הכנסת תוכן השורות במערך הכללי********/
            $row =array(
                'index_row'         =>  get_row_index(),
                'date_registered'   =>  get_sub_field('Date_typed'),
                'type'              =>  get_sub_field('type'),
                'ID_type'           =>  get_sub_field('id_type'),
                'category_name'     =>  get_sub_field('category_expenses'),
                'ID_category'       =>  get_sub_field('id_cat'),
                'dete_in_payment'   =>  get_sub_field('Date_payment'),
                'Amount'            =>  get_sub_field('total'),
                'method_payment'    =>  get_sub_field('method')
            );
            $fileds[$row['ID_type']]['content'][$row['ID_category']]['rows_registered'][]=$row;
        endwhile;
    endif;

    return $fileds;

}

//פונקציה לחובות    
private function debts($post_id){

    $a =array();
    $fileds = array();

    if( have_rows('debts', $post_id) ):
        while(have_rows('debts', $post_id) ): the_row();

            /*****הוצאת כמות שיש מכל קטגוריה***********/
            array_push($a, get_sub_field('id_cat', $post_id));
            $count_rows_registered = array_count_values($a);

    endwhile;
    endif;

    if( have_rows('types_income', 'option') ):
        while(have_rows('types_income', 'option') ): the_row();
            $type_no = get_sub_field('type_income_no');
            $title = get_sub_field('type_income_name');
            if( have_rows('cat_income', 'option') ):
                while( have_rows('cat_income', 'option') ): the_row();
                    $cat_income_no = get_sub_field('cat_income_no');
                    $cat_income_name = get_sub_field('cat_income_name');
                    if( have_rows('settings_cat') ):
                    while( have_rows('settings_cat') ): the_row();
                    $day_field  = get_sub_field('day_in_months');
                    $month_field = get_sub_field('months');
                    endwhile;
                    endif;                   
                    $fileds[$type_no]['name']=$title;
                    $fileds[$type_no]['content'][$cat_income_no]['name']= $cat_income_name;
                    $fileds[$type_no]['content'][$cat_income_no]['settings']=[
                        'day_field' => $day_field,
                        'month_field' => $month_field
                        ];
                    $fileds[$type_no]['content'][$cat_income_no]['count_rows_registered']=$count_rows_registered[$cat_income_no];
                    $fileds[$type_no]['content'][$cat_income_no]['rows_registered']=[];

                endwhile;
            endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;


    if( have_rows('debts', $post_id) ):
        while(have_rows('debts', $post_id) ): the_row();
            /********הכנסת תוכן השורות במערך הכללי********/
            $row =array(
                'index_row'         =>  get_row_index(),
                'date_registered'   =>  get_sub_field('Date_typed'),
                'type'              =>  get_sub_field('type'),
                'ID_type'           =>  get_sub_field('id_type'),
                'category_name'     =>  get_sub_field('category_debts'),
                'ID_category'       =>  get_sub_field('id_cat'),
                'dete_in_payment'   =>  get_sub_field('total_debt'),
                'Amount'            =>  get_sub_field('total'),
                'method_payment'    =>  get_sub_field('method')
            );
            $fileds[$row['ID_type']]['content'][$row['ID_category']]['rows_registered'][]=$row;
        endwhile;
    endif;

    return $fileds;

}

}
```

Again I note that when I put the class code inside the function directly - it works

Comment: Please include the code of what you've attempted in the question.

Comment: Soon I will add

Comment: I added it in response

Comment: That's not how this site works. Responses must be answers. Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new, how do you edit?

Comment: I found how to edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Use include (yourclass.php) only if the file yourclass.php is on the same folder. Otherwise you will need to put the full path to your file or use a variable for the plugin path:
public $plugin_path;
$this->plugin_path = plugin_dir_path( dirname( dirname( **FILE** ) ) );

and include the file using plugin_path.

Comment: I wrote like this:
`include (get_stylesheet_directory_uri (). /fileName.php);` The file itself in the root directory of the daughter template

Comment: make sure to put the quotes: include (get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/fileName.php');

Comment: Yes yes, that's how I originally wrote.

Comment: make sure you are using get_stylesheet_directory_uri() function for the right purpose - you need to check WP codex and also check this link maybe you will find useful info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349068/how-to-get-child-theme-url-in-wordpress

Comment: It's okay, I used it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you've spelt the filename incorrectly:

```
include_once(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fileds.php');
```

"fileds.php" should be "fields.php", judging by what you called it elsewhere in your question.

Secondly, on many (if not most) severs you can't use a URL with `include_once`. You need to get the *path* to the file. Use `get_theme_file_path()` to do this:

```
include_once get_theme_file_path( 'fields.php' );
```